# First derivative of $\sqrt[\large 5]{\frac{t^3 + 1}{t + 1}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have yet another derivative I need help with. I have to differentiate :

$$\sqrt[\uproot{3}{\Large 5}]{\frac{t^3 + 1}{t + 1}}$$

with respect to $t$.

I had two thoughts about this, use the chain rule then the quotient rule and multiply out, but then I am left with a mess of:

$$\left(\frac{t^3+1}{t+1}\right)^{-4/5}\cdot\frac{0.6t^3+0.6t^2-0.2t^4+0.2t}{(t+1)^2}$$

This is turning into a real mess and the answer I should get is:

$$\frac{2t-1}{5(t^2-t+1)^{4/5}}$$

Am I going the correct way about this or should I try a different route?

Thanks

Comment: How about logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: Use the notation `\sqrt[n]{x}` for the $n$th root of $x$, use parentheses when raising fractions to powers (use `\left(` and `\right)` to make the parentheses correctly sized) and use `$$...$$` to make displayed equations (larger, centered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process you describe one way to approach this: you can  use both the chain rule and the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule). But it looks to me as though you misunderstand the quotient rule:

$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

$$h'(x) = \frac{f'(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

where the factors in the numerator are **multiplied**, not added. (It also looks like you multiplied the coefficients by $1/5$?)

In your case, the rational function within the 5th root is $$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{t^3 + 1}{t+1}$$

$$f(x) = t^3 + 1, \implies f'(x) = 3t^2;\quad g(x) = t+ 1\implies g'(x) = 1$$

$$h'(x) = \frac{f'(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot g'(x)}{g^2(x)} $$
$$h'(x) = \frac{3t^2(t+1) - (t^3 +1)\cdot 1}{(t+1)^2}\;\;=\;\;\frac{2t^3 + 3t^2 - 1}{(t+1)^2}$$

Now, multiply $h'(x)$ with the result you got for the first factor: $$\frac 15\left(\frac{t^3+1}{t+1}\right)^{-4/5}= \left(\frac{t+1}{t^3 + 1}\right)^{4/5}$$

Which gives us:

$$\frac 15\left(\frac{t+1}{t^3 + 1}\right)^{4/5}\cdot \frac{2t^3 + 3t^2 - 1}{(t+1)^2}$$

Now, we can simplify.  (The Chaz's method greatly simplifies the process of taking the derivative of your function. But I think it is a good idea to ensure you understand the **quotient rule**.)

Chaz's tip will also simplify the left factor above to $\left(\dfrac{1}{t^2 - t + 1}\right)^{4/5}$. After that, there is really no need to simplify. Answers can be correct, yet not match the "textbook's solution" perfectly, simply based on how we choose to simplify.

$$\left(\frac{2t - 1}{5(t^2 + t - 1)^{4/5}}\right)$$

Comment: Okay, so then I get: $/frac {-3t^3+3t^2+3t-1} {t+1}$, what direction should I take from here?

Comment: Ugh, I cant get the notation to work but It reads the same as above except t+1 squared is the denominator

Comment: The slash in front of "frac" should be \

Comment: It really is a good idea to note that $(t^3 + 1)$ divided by $t+1 = t^2 - t + 1$, as The Chaz notes in his answer. That greatly simplifies the derivative, but also the simplification of having used the quotient rule with the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really explained everything and I will try the simplification later on.  Once again thanks.

Comment: In simplifying the above (note final simplification), we have that $$h'(x) = \frac{2t^3 + 3t^2 - 1}{(t+1)^2} = \frac{(t+1)^2(2t - 1)}{(t+1)^2} = 2t - 1$$

Comment: @amWhy: very nice discussion! +1 Off to go get my car (may not be done until 9 PM! Ugh!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** simplify the radicand to $t^2 -t + 1$ before differentiating.

Comment: (Then you'll have the Power Rule + the Chain Rule, and only one step to simplify the result into the answer you "should" get.)

Comment: Is it significant that this simplification eliminates a singularity at $t=-1$?

Comment: Well, the function is not defined for $t=-1$

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to take the fifth power of both sides and get
$$y^5(t+1)=t^3+1.$$
Differentiate both sides, using *implicit differentiation* on the left.
We get 
$$y^5+5(t+1)y^4 y'=3t^2.$$
Now solve for $y'$.

For more complicated examples of a similar kind, I would suggest *logarithmic differentiation.* Take the (natural) logarithm of both sides. We get
$$\log y=\frac{1}{5}\log(1+t^3)-\frac{1}{5}\log(1+t).$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$. On the left we get $\frac{y'}{y}$. Differentiation on the right is straightforward.

Comment: Any insight on your preference? These methods seem *significantly more involved* than just taking the derivative of the simplified quotient. Of course, these methods generalize...

Comment: Depends on context. Often logarithmic differentiation. But the first is useful when we want the derivative at a particular point. Avoiding fractions, negatives until late can be a useful way to avoid errors. As to significantly more involved, I would just say less familiar.

Comment: I will have to do more reading on logarithmic differentiation as I have not used it before.

Comment: It is the only sensible thing for, say, $y=x\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{-3x^2}\cos x$. (There are less contrived real life examples where it is useful!)